# Can we reclone a git repository from the existing local repository

Tags: git, git-clone, git-revert

Since git is a distributed VCS, it should have complete history of changes done to a repository.

So can we **extract** that version of repo which was cloned first?

Actually I have done a lot of changes in my existing local repo. and do not want to revert back to the original state by losing the data. But I want to extract the original repository(which I cloned initially) to some other location using existing git objects(blob/tree).

Note : I don't have the access to git server now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
git clone SOURCE_PATH NEW_PATH # clones everything you have committed up to now
cd NEW_PATH                    # go to new clone, don't modify the pre-existing one
git reset --hard REV           # REV is the revision to "rewind" to (from git log)
```

So you need to figure out explicitly which revision to go back to (Git probably doesn't know which revision you originally cloned, but probably you can figure it out).  The first step is just to clone from your local disk to your local disk in a different directory so you can keep your existing work untouched.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you cloned your project from a remote repo (call the local repo - `local_repo_1`), after that you have made some changes to it (uncommited) and now you want to have another copy of the original cloned git repo, but from the `local_repo_1` and not from remote.

You can do this in the following these steps:

1. Save your work in a stash
   `git stash save stash_name  //give any name to your stash, say local_repo_2`
2. Now you'd be left with the bare repo that you cloned from the remote, you can clone it by:
   move out from your git repo
   `cd ..`
   clone
   `git clone /path/to/local_repo_1 local_repo_2  // local_repo_2  is the new repo`
   In case you had some local commits too, then do a
   `git log`
   and reset it to the desired SHA
   `git reset --hard SHA`
3. And finally you can go back to your `local_repo_1` and apply your stash
   `git stash apply`

Voila, now you have:
**local_repo_1**:  your changes that you had made over and above the bare repo, back to its original form.
**local_repo_2**: a copy of the remote repo without your local changes

Answer (score 1):

You can add this script to your bash

```
reclone () {
    set -e
    basename=${PWD##*/}
    remoteurl=$(git remote get-url --push origin)
    cd ..
    echo $basename
    echo $remoteurl
    rm -rf $basename
    git clone $remoteurl
    cd $basename
    set +e
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it absolutely.

Try something like this

Lets say you have cloned to

```
c:/originalRepository
```

switch to a new folder and say

```
git clone file:///c:/originalRepository
```

You will have your repo as cloned earlier.

Comment: @MichaelVer If the original state is required, either we need to switch the branch to the commit we need as previous one or do reset --hard. It is as same as server. If there were new commits in git server and you want the code to be in previous commit !! The above helps to create a new repo from the existing repo with the commits up to date.

Answer (score -2):

You could just make a new branch

```
git checkout -b original-state REV
```

Comment: The original poster wants to clone his local repo, and this won't do that, and it doesn't really solve the actual problem.

Comment: @Cupcake It all depends. I read the question more like viewing and managing past versions in Git. Of course one can create an additional instances of the existing repository ending up with several folders with different revisions. I just do not think it would be the best practice.

Comment: Some more explanation to that effect would make this a better answer then.